# The Harmonic Language in 60's Sci Fi

Tags: composition

Does anybody know what techniques John Williams, Jerry Goldsmith, and others used in this genre. I hear octatonicism, pitch sets and some tone rows. Is anyone aware of techniques or disciplines (harmonic frameworks, licks, sounds, orchestration tips, recording techniques, or any kind of resource relevant to their creation process) that will allow for achieving similar compositions or sounds.

Comment: Like pretty much every successful person, their trick is there is no trick. They worked very hard and mastered their craft - that’s how they wrote such excellent music so quickly.

Comment: The reason this question is closed is because any reasonable answer to it would be very, very long. That's because the question itself is extremely broad. There are hundreds of techniques used in creating an orchestral soundtrack. It can easily take years to learn to sound like any composer. One way to ask a better question would be something like "How can I learn to compose like John Williams?" (or pick any one composer).